# parsing error unexpected token mailtransport

Tags: android, firebase

In my android app when user enters wrong PASSWORD more times then i want send email to user using firebase functions with download link of picture captured so i created function below.
So i push email and download link to firebase and when data gets added following function gets triggered but whenever im trying to deploy this function cli giving me error that mailtransport is unexpected..

```
exports.sendMails = functions.database.ref('/failedAttemps/{email2}/{attemptsid}')
.onWrite((data, context) =>
{
  const email2 = context.params.email2;
  const attemptsid = context.params.attemptsid;
  //const sender_id = context.params.sender_id;
  //const mees = context.params.message_not;
 // contentss = mees;
 const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: "******@gmail.com",
    pass: "****@****",
  },
});
  const email = admin.database().ref(`/Notification/${email2}/${attemptsid}/email`);
  email.once("value", function(snapshot){
     emails = snapshot.val();
  });
  const naam = admin.database().ref(`/Notification/${email2}/${attemptsid}/dlink`);
  naam.once("value", function(snapshot){
    dlinks = snapshot.val();
  });

 // console.log('message :' , contentss);


  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"LetsTalk" <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: emails,
  };


  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = 'Someone tried to login to you account';
  mailOptions.text = `${dlink}Thanks you for subscribing to our newsletter. You will receive our next weekly newsletter.`; 

  try {
    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
 //   console.log(`New ${subscribed ? '' : 'un'}subscription confirmation email sent to:`, val.email);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error);
  }
return null;



});
```

Every time i try to deploy function on firebase.This error pops up[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNdby.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be you are using `await` without first indicating it is an `async` function.

Try replacing your first lines with:

```
exports.sendMails = functions.database.ref('/failedAttemps/{email2}/{attemptsid}')
.onWrite(async (data, context) =>
{
```